# Changing DateTime Format from one form to another

Tags: c#, linq

I wish to make the "tdate" format as "d, MMM, yyyy" and then send it from one form which has a data grid view to a different form which contains a textbox.

So far I tried to make it as:

```
 frm.txtDate.Text = (this.dgvEvents.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString("d, MMM, yyyy"));
```

This is the code of the class :-

```
public int CreateTicket(string tName, DateTime tDate, string type, string venue)
{
    EventTicketEntities database = new EventTicketEntities();
    Ticket t = new Ticket();
    t.TicketName = tName;
    t.TicketDate = tDate;
    t.TicketType = type;
    t.TicketVenue = venue;
    database.Tickets.Add(t);//We ADD our promoter to our advertiser table!
    return database.SaveChanges(); //returns the affected rows ....
}
```

And this code is to show a new form when the "Proceed" button is clicked.

```
public void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ticketForm frm = new ticketForm();

     frm.txtName.Text = (this.dgvEvents.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
     frm.txtDate.Text = (this.dgvEvents.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
     frm.txtType.Text = (this.dgvEvents.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
     frm.txtVenue.Text = (this.dgvEvents.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
    //pass selected index of combobox 

    frm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cell.Value` is of type `object`, you need to cast it to `DateTime` to apply customized formatting.

```
((DateTime)this.dgvEvents.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value)
                   .ToString("d, MMM, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also supply `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to keep your date separator `,`.

*This would only work, if the data in your your cell is `DateTime`  type to begin with, otherwise you will end up with exception*

Comment: Perfect, just perfect! Thanks Mr. Habib!